# Is there any way how to get dotted line around circle image, but only eg one side

Tags: css

I have dotted line all around image but i need only one side!

[image]

```
.img_pizza:before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 7px dotted chocolate;
    top: -60px;
    left: -60px;
    right: -60px;
    bottom: -60px;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make only one border visible and do a rotation:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px dashed;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  border-top-color:transparent;
  border-left-color:transparent;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```